# 2 select lists with identical data, how to remove identical data on select list number 2 and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

everyone. I am working on currency exchange rate calculator with jQuery.

I have 2 select lists (with the currency name and currency price in USD) and 2 inputs (from_amount and to_amount), here's the picture for better understanding of my case:

[image]

First problem: As you can see there's 2 identical value in two select lists. How can i avoid that behavior? If in **Exchange from** selected Bitcoin, then in **Exchange to** should be another currency, let's say Dogecoin, and vice versa, because we cannot exchange the same currency.

Second problem:
**Exchange from:**

```
<select id="from-amount" name="currencies" class="form-control">
  <option value="750.00000000">Bitcoin</option>
  <option value="0.00024000">Dogecoin</option>
</select>
```

Value has the price in USD, 1 Bitcoin costs 750$ (approx). When a user fills any number in **You give** it should automatically convert to **You receive**, and vice versa.

In my case this formula would work: (750 * amountYouGive) / currencyPriceInUSD in one way, but what if user would be filling **You receive** input? Please, any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Values are converted back and forth according to both send and receive amounts and currencies.

The calculation to go from amount sent in currency 2 to amount received in currency 1 is :

x = (received*currencyReceived)/currencySent

```js
$('#yousend').keyup(function(){
     var result = parseFloat($('#from-amount').val()) * parseFloat($(this).val()) / parseFloat($('#to-amount').val())
    $('#youreceive').val( result );
});

$('#youreceive').keyup(function(){
    var result = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($('#to-amount').val())/ parseFloat($('#from-amount').val()) 
    $('#yousend').val( parseFloat(result));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="from-amount" name="currencies" class="form-control">
  <option value="750.00000000">Bitcoin</option>
  <option value="0.00024000">Dogecoin</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='yousend' placeholder="send">
<select id="to-amount" name="currenciesto" class="form-control">
  <option value="750.00000000">Bitcoin</option>
  <option value="0.00024000">Dogecoin</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='youreceive' placeholder="receive">
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't solve both of my problems. In your example i can see Bitcoin selected in both selects. Also if i put "1" in **You give** it doesn't conver (750 * 1 ) / 0.00024. Your example puts "1" in **You receive**

Comment: How to avoid "Bitcoin" on the second select list, if it was chosen in the first one?